# Loading an image with getDownloadURL() from firebase storage do not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, nuxt.js

It seems like getDownloadURL() is not working and gives an error.

I use nuxtjs and want to display an image on browser. The image was uploaded manually on firebase storage.

I tried

```
npm install xmlhttprequest
```

since the error was xmlhttprequest related.

but didn't change anything. I also think I really should install xmlhttprequest or not... because that seems something people do not use on nuxt or vue? I use firebase realtime db in other part and it is working fine using axios.

This is my code.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage.ref("/animals/cat.png");
storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url); 
});
```

and I get this error on terminal.

```
node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.cjs.js:672
        this.xhr_ = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    ^
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the Cloud Storage for Firebase client library on a server.  It's only intended to work in a browser environment.  Browsers provide a native XMLHttpRequest object, and that's what the client library is assuming.  Installing the node module xmlhttprequest won't simply provide an implementation that will automatically import into the Firease SDK's own module.

Comment: I wonder why it is very hard to find a way to get an image path from firebase storage. That sounds like a basic thing to me. I am missing something obvious, maybe?